# I need an advice for nonlinear optimization

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Nowadays I am working on nonlinear mathematical model. The model is mixed integer  My objective function is basically like that

Min Z= A'X+B'Y + exp(w)   // A and B  constants ; X and Y and w are variable

s.t.

.....

..... // the constraints linear

.....

exp(w)*C<=D  // C is parameter and D is variable

How can I solve this problem ? I know it is hard to find the optimum solution but at least can you advise me some methods or solvers which  solve it at least near optimum ?  I tried it on LINGO but LINGO finds just local optimum .  All the ideas are appreciated

Thank you so much

Comment: This may well be convex. If not an easy approach would be a piecewise linear representation of `exp(w)`. Or use a global MINLP solver.

Comment: Thank you Erwin , I did piecewise linear appro.  and tried to solve on CPLEX but it took too much time for even small instances. (probably it is because the approxiation is done for objective function). Can you tell me which "global" MINLP  can solve this problem? Second question , I learned SOS2 type approximation but I do not how to use it ? If you know something about it, can you advise me a paper or example ?  Thank you

Comment: I don't see why a piecewise linear approximation for this case would be very slow. Anyway, some references on SOS2 variables are [GAMS: Piecewise linear functions with SOS2 variables](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2009/06/gams-piecewise-linear-functions-with.html) and [Model Building in Mathematical Programming](https://www.amazon.com/Model-Building-Mathematical-Programming-Williams/dp/1118443330). Of course, this is just a way to implement piecewise linear functions, and it likely to be identical to what Cplex did.

Comment: Thank you so much for information Erwin, I just wondering something, Since you are expert optimizer, I always follow your blog, I think you can give me good idea. In my objective function actually in exp(w ) ,  w, is negative value and full function is  A'X+B'Y + (1-exp(w)) . Do you think this structure for (1-1-exp(w)) causes a problem ?

Comment: I think that would make the objective non-convex.

Comment: Sorry , I am very beginner . In this case, the approximation approaches will not work ?  or should I use directly suitable solver , I tried to solve the problem with Lingo. Which way would be fine to solve this problem ? Million thanks

Comment: I think it will make it more difficult. I can always be wrong of course: the best way is to test it yourself.